# Mixing `conntrack` with `--protocol`, etc trying to rewrite my rules.v4

Tags: networking, iptables

I just read [`iptables` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables). And it appears that with `conntrack` module, I should use/prefer `--ctproto` to `--protocol`?

I will better show you what I used up until now, I migrated at some point to **`ct*`**. Anyway, here it is:

```
$ cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4 
*filter
:INPUT      DROP      [0:0]
:FORWARD    DROP      [0:0]
:OUTPUT     ACCEPT    [0:0]
--append INPUT --in-interface lo --match comment --comment "Allow loopback" --jump ACCEPT
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate INVALID --match comment --comment "Drop invalid packets" --jump DROP
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW --protocol tcp ! --syn --match comment --comment "Reject new non-syn TCP" --jump REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --protocol tcp --match tcp --destination-port 22 --source 192.168.0.0/24 --match comment --comment "Allow local SSH on default port" --jump ACCEPT
--append INPUT --protocol icmp --icmp-type echo-request --match limit --limit 2/second --limit-burst 5 --match comment --comment "Allow only ping and within limits" --jump ACCEPT
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --match comment --comment "Normal traffic" --jump ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

---

So, I tried to rewrite it as follows:

```
*filter
:INPUT      DROP      [0:0]
:FORWARD    DROP      [0:0]
:OUTPUT     ACCEPT    [0:0]
--append INPUT --in-interface lo --match comment --comment "Allow loopback" --jump ACCEPT
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate INVALID --match comment --comment "Drop invalid packets" --jump DROP
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW --ctproto tcp ! --syn --match comment --comment "Reject new non-syn TCP" --jump REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --ctproto tcp --match tcp --destination-port 22 --source 192.168.0.0/24 --match comment --comment "Allow local SSH on default port" --jump ACCEPT
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctproto icmp --icmp-type echo-request --match limit --limit 2/second --limit-burst 5 --match comment --comment "Allow only ping and within limits" --jump ACCEPT
--append INPUT --match conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED --match comment --comment "Normal traffic" --jump ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Getting these and possibly other errors if I try differently:

```
# iptables-restore < rules.v4-ct 
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "--syn"
Error occurred at line: 7
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
# iptables-restore < rules.v4-ct 
iptables-restore v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "--icmp-type"
Error occurred at line: 9
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
# iptables-restore < rules.v4-ct 
iptables-restore: line 11 failed
# iptables-restore < rules.v4-ct 
Bad argument `COMMIT'
Error occurred at line: 11
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

Thanks if you can shed light into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks:

- I'm curious to know where it has been advised one should favor using `--ctproto tcp`. Is there any reference?
- the precise [URL link in OP for manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) is 10+ years outdated: for example it doesn't include `conntrack` match module's `--ctreplsrcport` which is used in a remark at the end of this answer. It wasn't yet split into two man pages: [`iptables`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html) (base) and [`iptables-extensions`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html) where most of the interesting documentation (matches and targets) exists today. Though I favor Debian man pages because links to parameters and sub-commands (like the [`conntrack` match](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#conntrack)) are often present.

About the problem:

- `--protocol` is a built-in feature of `iptables` not requiring an extra match module (that would be described in `iptables-extensions(8)`). It's not a match module parameter that changes its dependency to multiple modules.
- using a module specific parameter without having the module loaded can't work

  - `--syn` is part of [`-m tcp`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#tcp) and can't be used without loading this module

    line 7 fails because of this
  - `--icmp-type` is part of [`-m icmp`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#icmp_(IPv4-specific)) and can't be used without loading this module

    line 9 fails because of this
- protocol specific modules require the protocol to be stated

  Stating a protocol (eg: `-p tcp`) automatically attempts to load the module of the same name (eg: `-m tcp`). The reverse is not true. That's why the `tcp` or `icmp` modules are rarely explicitly written, but are actually always present, as would a `iptables-save` show back. This isn't clearly documented, but if going that way and the documentation were to be *strictly* followed, one would always have to write  `-p tcp` and `-m tcp` to respect the current documentation.

  - TCP

    > [`tcp`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#tcp)
    >
    > **These extensions can be used if `--protocol tcp` is specified.**
    > It provides the following options:

    once line 7 got `-m tcp` added to, lines 7 and 8 still fail (apparently at the kernel validation level) because of this
  - ICMP

    > [`icmp`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#icmp_(IPv4-specific)) (IPv4-specific)
    >
    > **This extension can be used if `--protocol icmp` is specified.**
    > It provides the following option:

    line 9 fails (apparently at the kernel validation level) because of this

So in the end even if one can use `--ctproto tcp`, whenever features not part of it are needed, `-p tcp -m tcp` is still required. Ditto for ICMP. It's probably not worth using the `conntrack` module for this when more specific methods are available.

Also `conntrack` does lookups in the *conntrack* table which could be more costly than a specific method (but actually once the lookup was done (at prio -200 by the *conntrack* facility), [a reference to the entry is cached](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/include/linux/skbuff.h?h=v5.15#n662) in the packet's skbuff, and the state is also made directly available).

Some remarks:

- [`nf_conntrack_tcp_loose`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n122)

  At the system (network namespace) level, this filter:

  ```
  -A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW --ctproto tcp -m tcp ! --syn -m comment --comment "Reject new non-syn TCP" -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
  ```

  except for the final `REJECT` target could be replaced with:

  ```
  sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_loose=0
  ```

  which would now classify such packets as invalid and be dropped (instead of rejected in OP's rule) by the INVALID rule check instead. Loose mode is enabled by default to allow temporarily interrupted traffic (eg: reboot of a stateful routing firewall) to recover.
- line 8 could actually be done *without* `-p tcp -m tcp`

  Because for this case [`-m conntrack`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#conntrack) has the features to replace it.

  As a nat/PREROUTING rule could have altered the original destination port which could be different than 22, `--ctreplsrcport 22` is chosen below over the more natural `--ctorigdstport 22`.

  ```
  -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --ctproto tcp --ctreplsrcport 22 --match comment --comment "Allow local SSH on default port" --jump ACCEPT
  ```

  or even (the rarely used nat/INPUT happening after filter/INPUT despite some documentation telling otherwise, no change happens to the source and the natural `--ctorigsrc` can be used):

  ```
  -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED --ctproto tcp --ctreplsrcport 22 --ctorigsrc 192.168.0.0/24 --match comment --comment "Allow local SSH on default port" --jump ACCEPT
  ```

Comment: 1) http://www.iptables.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html I am unsure how do create direct link to section `3.3 conntrack patch`, just look it up, example there: `iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED --ctproto tcp -j ACCEPT` I see it is a forwarding rule, but still, it confused me. I'll read all your text down. Thank you kindly for your effort!

Comment: Despite being from official iptables.org (now https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.3 ) it's outdated: it tells [conntrack](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NF_CONNTRACK.html) is a "new" patch superseding the state match module while this has been the case for 10+ years ( ~ kernel 2.6.15 or 2.6.25). It didn't include initially features like --ctreplsrcport etc. It doesn't mention that it supersedes the basic matches, only `-m state` (which is really the case). It's still probably useful for simple cases like the example: no need for a 2nd module.

Comment: Now the other options (--ctorigdstport etc.) have more concrete use. For example with NAT context: it allows to match a flow or packet that was NAT-ed in a certain way, for example to distinguish a port 2222 NAT-ed to 22 from a port that was sent as 22 and wasn't changed.

Comment: Good job! Honestly, you explained it perfect. Many thanks.